# Knp Paginate Bundle sort with custom url

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to change the sortable url and the first step is override the `sortable_link.html.twig` template

```
<a href="{{ path('my_custom_route', {'key': key,'sort':key,'direction':direction}) }}">{{ title }}</a>
```

But the sort doesn't run...

Some research I have come to the `Knp\Component\Pager\Event\Subscriber\Sortable\Doctrine\ORM\QuerySubscriber` and I found the $_GET use for retrieve the data!

How I can override this Subscriber for use my Symfony2 standard routes?

Answer (score 0):

having the same problem. I really haven't found a **clear** non-hacky way to fix this yet. You can **make it work** with a terrible, ugly and just wrong hack by setting $_GET parameters manually in your controller.

```
public function myAction($page, $sort, $direction)
{
    $_GET['sort'] = $sort;
    $_GET['direction'] = $direction;

    // ... your code
}
```

Comment: I think this is the only way at the moment, since classes like Knp\Component\Pager\Event\Subscriber\Sortable\Doctrine\ORM\QuerySubscriber refer to the $_GET superglobal to do their sorting...